# C# as sender and python as receiver in Azure event hub

Tags: azure, message, azure-eventhub

I have an IoT device that is connected to Azure event hub. I'm trying to make this device communicate with azure databricks and azure event hub is placed in between as a middleware. The problem is that after we are able to send messages via ".NET framework", it is never shown in messages received in "python" command line (we should do that as we work separately for each part)

I followed the guidelines [.NET framework as sender](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-framework-getstarted-send) and [python as receiver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send), and this doesn't work.

I am seeing that there are spikes in the request and message graphs under event hub stream instances, but it just never shows in the receiver

==================================UPDATE==================================

Just deleted the eventhub and recreated and it seems work.

However, messages are received in the form of long strings something like this below:

```
Received: 662a2a44-4414-4cb5-a9e9-a08d12a417e0
Received: b68ef8f8-305f-4726-84e4-f35b76de30c5
Received: e94dfb73-972c-47b4-baef-1ab41b06be28
Received: 8eda384d-f79d-4cdf-9db3-fe5c2156553b
Received: d154283f-a8c2-4a4c-a7d5-e8d8129b568d
Received: 3e3e190e-f883-416c-a5be-b8cd8547d152
Received: e218c63b-85b3-4f4f-8f04-cb5ffc6d8921
Received: 0adec5ad-e351-4151-ba56-01093e0f383d
Received 8 messages in 0.05406975746154785 seconds
```

This happens when I read the messages in format below:

`print("Received: {}".format(event_data.body_as_str(encoding='UTF-8')))`

Comment: How many partitions do you have in eventhubs? I check the python code, it only receives from the partition id 0.

Comment: @IvanYang  Hi. Thanks for your help.  we do have only two partitions '0' and '1' and never used partition '1' from both ends.

Comment: so in your c# code for sender, you just send to partition 0, right?

Comment: @IvanYang yes, that's correct.

Comment: can you share your code for both sender and receiver? then I can test it at my side.

Comment: @ivanYang Hi. Thanks for help. I just updated and it seems work, but I am having trouble with reading them.

Comment: which format do you expect?

Comment: @IvanYang So, basically, those strings are not the original message I sent. The original messages include current date time and number in range from 0 to 9.

Comment: please show us the sender code, and the source data.

Comment: @IvanYang Hi. The code is exactly the same as the one linked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just give it a try, and I can repro your issue. And here are something you need to check.

1.In you sender(in c#), you should make sure your message to send is correct. Like below:

```
    static void SendingRandomMessages()
    {
        var eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, eventHubName);
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                // make sure the message is correct.
                var message = i+":"+Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+":"+DateTime.Now;

                Console.WriteLine("{0} > Sending message: {1}", DateTime.Now, message);
                var myeventdata = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
                eventHubClient.Send(myeventdata);
                i++;
                //eventHubClient.Send(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)));
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} > Exception: {1}", DateTime.Now, exception.Message);
                Console.ResetColor();
            }

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
```

2.There seems some delay for the receiver(in python), so I execute the python receiver about 3 times, and I can see the expected output. The screenshot as below:

[image]

**Update 1022:** as we discussed in the comment, there is a solution for fixing just receiving even / odd number event data.

In you sender(in c#), use the code below, which sends event data to partition 0:

```
        static void SendingRandomMessages()
        {
            var eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, eventHubName);
            var myclient = eventHubClient.CreatePartitionedSender("0");
            int i = 30;

            while (true)
            {
                var message = i + ":" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ":" + DateTime.Now;

                Console.WriteLine("{0} > Sending message: {1}", DateTime.Now, message);
                var myeventdata = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
                myclient.Send(myeventdata);
                i++;
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
          }
```

then in your receiver(in python), specify the partition to 0(use this `PARTITION = "0"`), then you can get all the event data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way, do you happen to know how to receive very recent data only? I am getting all the messages previously sent. Besides, I am only receiving either even numbers or odd numbers only.

Comment: @BrianLee, for python, I'm now also trying to figure out how to get the recent data(if using c#, it always gets the recent data). For only receiving even / odd numbers data, are you using c# as sender, and python as receiver?

Comment: For your second question, yes. C# as sender and python as receiver

Comment: @BrianLee, ok, and I will update you when I find the solution. By the way, here is an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58406060/eventhub-reading-data-as-list-in-python) you posted previously, if you have a solution, please post an answer to it. :)

Comment: Yeah I commented on that. Thanks.

Comment: @BrianLee, just fix the 2nd issue(only receive even / odd number event data), please refer to the update section in my post. And for the first issue, I will let you know if I find solution :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201241/discussion-between-ivan-yang-and-brian-lee).

Comment: @BrianLee, for the issue about how to receive very recent data, I find a way to do that. Can you please post a new issue about that?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58497804/how-to-receive-the-recent-data-only-in-event-hub)

Comment: @BrianLee, I see, I will post it later :)